# Problem with Logstash-Plug in-JMS and Weblogic 12.2.1

Tags: jms, logstash, weblogic

I have installed Weblogic 12.2.1 and the latest Logstash 7.5.2 version as well as the JMS plugin v3.1.2. I am struggling with the JMS plugin, and I have already set the .conf and .yml, but it doesn't work!

In the `destination` field the documentation and the examples suggest no JNDI name, just the queue or topic name!

The input of the `jms.conf`:

```
input {
   jms {
      pub_sub => false
      include_header => false
      include_properties => false
      include_body => true
      use_jms_timestamp => false
      yaml_file => "/home/chris/Downloads/logstash-7.5.2/config/jms.yml"
      yaml_section => "weblogic"
      destination => "DemoQ"
   }
}
```

The `jms.yml`:

```
weblogic:
  :jndi_name: jms/DemoCF
  :jndi_context:
    java.naming.factory.initial: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
    java.naming.provider.url: t3://localhost:7001
    java.naming.factory.url.pkgs: javax.naming:javax.jms
    java.naming.security.principal: weblogic
    java.naming.security.credentials: *****!
  :require_jars:
    - /home/chris/Downloads/wlogic/fmw_12.2.1.0.0_wls_quick_Disk1_1of1/wls12210/wlserver/server/lib/wlthint3client.jar
    - /home/chris/Downloads/wlogic/fmw_12.2.1.0.0_wls_quick_Disk1_1of1/wls12210/wlserver/server/lib/wljmsclient.jar
    - /home/chris/Downloads/wlogic/fmw_12.2.1.0.0_wls_quick_Disk1_1of1/wls12210/wlserver/server/lib/wlclient.jar
```

and the ouput of the Logstash:

```
[2020-01-31T14:50:10,284][WARN ][logstash.inputs.jms ][main] JMS Consumer Died {:exception=>"Java::WeblogicJmsCommon::JMSException", :exception_message=>"[JMSExceptions:045101]The destination name passed to the createTopic or createQueue "DemoQ" is invalid. If the destination name does not contain a "/" character, then it must be the name of a distributed destination that is available in the cluster to which the client is attached. If it does contain a "/" character, then the string before the "/" must be the name of a JMS server or a ".". The string after the "/" is the name of a the desired destination. If the "./" version of the string is used then any destination with the given name on the local WebLogic Server instance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days I figured this out! In the field of destination use:
**jmsmodulename!destinationname** (from docs of Oracle ) ,
for a clustered environment!!
**Neither "/" nor "./"**

Answer (score 0):

Logstash doesn't use JNDI to lookup the destination but instead simply uses the JMS API to call [javax.jms.Session.createQueue()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#createQueue-java.lang.String-) (if `pubsub` is `false`) or [javax.jms.Session.createTopic()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#createTopic-java.lang.String-) (if `pubsub` is `true`).

Although I'm not very familiar with WebLogic it seems the error message that it is returning is pretty clear:

> The destination name passed to the createTopic or createQueue "DemoQ" is invalid. If the destination name does not contain a "/" character, then it must be the name of a distributed destination that is available in the cluster to which the client is attached. If it does contain a "/" character, then the string before the "/" must be the name of a JMS server or a ".". The string after the "/" is the name of a the desired destination. If the "./" version of the string is used then any destination with the given name on the local WebLogic Server instance

It indicates that your configuration is invalid, specifically this bit:

```
destination => "DemoQ"
```

It also appears to be recommending that you use this instead:

```
destination => "./DemoQ"
```

Comment: Thank you Justin for your response!! I have also tried with destination => "./DemoQ", but the distributed queue is still unrecognized.. maybe i should put a JMS server or a Module in the Path? the output of Logstash is ''' root_cause=>{:exception=>"Java::WeblogicJmsCommon::JMSException", :exception_message=>"[JMSExceptions:045102]A destination named \"DemoQ\" was not found on WebLogic Server instance \"AdminServer\"."}} '''